# Сохранение картинок на сервере из админки Django

Tags: heroku, django-admin

Интернет-магазин на Heroku.
При добавлении нового товара в панели администратора создаётся запись в базе данных, прописывается путь изображения, но сама картинка на сервере не сохраняется по указанному пути.
Проверил через терминал другие папки, тоже не нашел эту картинку.

На локальном сохранялось, указывал MEDIA_ROOT.

На реальном сервере либо вообще не сохранилась, либо не понятно где искать.